# Trying to detect chars in if-statement

Tags: java, string, if-statement, numbers, char

I'm having a bit of trouble with detecting a CHAR in an if statement.
I have a score integer, which i made in to a String, and from the string, i made a char Array.
My problem is, that when i try to detect what number the char is, it returns the "Error.png".

Please help me :)

code:

```
    scoreString = "" + score;
    System.out.println(scoreString + "  -  " + scoreString.length());
    scoreA = scoreString.toCharArray();
    for(int counter = 0; counter < scoreString.length(); counter++){
            Texture drawT;
            if(scoreA[counter] == 0) drawT = i0;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 1) drawT = i1;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 2) drawT = i2;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 3) drawT = i3;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 4) drawT = i4;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 5) drawT = i5;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 6) drawT = i6;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 7) drawT = i7;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 8) drawT = i8;
            else if(scoreA[counter] == 9) drawT = i9;
            else drawT = error;
            MainClass.batch.draw(drawT, 5 + (9 * counter), 95);
    }
```

Comment: "*it returns the "Error.png"*" > Is this your way of saying there is a compiler error? If so, please actually post the compiler error in the future.

Comment: Your if construct could be replaced by a nice array lookup: http://ideone.com/pQ0Yen - you just need to put your `i0` to `i9` variables into an array and access them like `i[0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scoreA[counter] == 1` compares a character to the numerical value of 1, which is not correct. `'1'` is not the same thing as `1`. In fact, `'1'` is actually equal to `31` in hex. Use something like:

```
if(scoreA[counter] == '0') drawT = i0;
else if(scoreA[counter] == '1') drawT = i1;
//continue on
```

I obviously included a short snippet but it should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You want character literals.
You need to write

```
if(scoreA[counter] == '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is thinking that the `char` representation for numbers are the same as the numbers themselves - they're not.  `chars` represent [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) characters (strictly speaking unicode but for this purpose we can just assume ASCII), so the code of the character `0` is NOT the number `0`.  To fix the problem you can just use `char` literals in your comparisons:

```
        if(scoreA[counter] == '0') drawT = i0;
        else if(scoreA[counter] == '1') drawT = i1;
        ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Always you have to set character literals with in the single coats

**i.e.**

```
scoreA[counter] == '0'
```